# How to describe the appearance for male or female

Tags: meaning

Can I use Immaculately Groomed for male or female?
If not what is the corresponding words for the male?
Thanks

Comment: It's fine for either - maybe even more appropriate for male than female, since men (typically) don't wear make up, so you might say "immaculately made-up" for a woman.

Answer (score 2):

Yes

"Grooming" in the context refers to how one carefully styles the hair or wears smart clothes. It can apply to both men and women, and is perhaps even more common for men than for women.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use this phrase for either a male or a female, perhaps a dog or a cat?

Instead, when males look good, we'd say they are "handsome", for females they look "beautiful".

Comment: Not really the same. "Grooming" refers to how well dressed the person is, how nicely they have their hair done, etc. "Handsome" and "beautiful" are usually used for more underlying aspects of appearance. It would be perfectly reasonable to say, "Bob is seriously overweight and has an ugly deformity on his face, but he is always well-groomed."

Comment: [There are over 20,000 Google Books results for "immaculately groomed"](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=immaculately+groomed), so I think you're in the minority on this one.

Comment: I agree with the other commentors.  [Here](https://film.avclub.com/immaculately-groomed-case-file-38-johnny-depp-in-mort-1798280802) are a [few](https://malestandard.com/the-insider-secrets-of-immaculately-groomed-men/) links to [articles](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/men/fashion-and-style/10420837/Well-groomed-or-over-preened-When-good-grooming-goes-bad.html) where either "immaculately groomed" or "well groomed" are used to refer to human men.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use it for both – though ordinarily you shouldn't capitalize it, as you've done in your question. If you want to be fancy (some would day pretentious), another option would be to use "soigné" for a man and "soignée" for a woman.